# Add an edit request feature for questions

Tags: feature-request, comments

### Why something like this would be useful

When new users ask questions they usually don't supply all the information that they should on the first go, and the comments end up looking something like:

> - Please show what you have tried so far
> - Edited the question
> - What is the expected output?
> - I added the expected output to the question
> - ...

So the comments section gets filled with unnecessary information and end up having to click on `show more comments` and scrolling down even further to check the rest of the comments.

Some flags (mainly "unclear what you're asking" and "too broad") could cover scenarios such as these. But usually when the posts of new users get closed they get discouraged and instead of editing the question, they just leave Stack Overflow.

### How it could work

I had a feature in mind that would allow users to post comments, and flag them as edit requests. The OP will then be able to delete that comment (only after editing the question) and the user that posted the comment will be notified.

These requests will still act as comments, and user will be able to respond to them, though it is debatable whether these subsequent comments should be deleted or not after the deletion of the original.

If the OP deletes the comment and the person that posted the comment feels that the OP didn't do a good enough job with the request, they could just open a subsequent one.

### Main issues

One big issue with this approach, is that people may respond to a request that will eventually get deleted, making the second comment obsolete/incomprehensible to other users. Here are some solutions for this issue:

- Delete all the replies to the deleted request. (This might also delete valuable information or valid queries. It might also cause the same problem that any subsequent replies to those second level replies).
- Make requests only visible to the OP. (This pretty much guarantees that OP will receive duplicate requests).
- Make the flag requests anonymous, so people can't tag the user that posted it. (People may still refer to the comment, without tagging.)

Another issue is that sometimes the line between comment and request may be blurry and thus people will not use the feature properly.

Comment: I don;t think it's a good idea to give normal users _any_ form of control over other users' comments...

Comment: All of this comments seem to indicate that the question can't be answered as is. This is exactly when it should be put on hold. Your proposal seems to imply that no questions should be closed unless it is completely off-topic (with which I don't agree).

Comment: Don't take downvote too rush - your post is OK but I afraid people don't agree with it - therefor the downvote.

Comment: *When new users ask questions they usually don't supply all the information that they should on the first go* --> and why users don't supply all the information in the first go? they should do, it's the easiest solution

Comment: @BDL I'm in no way implying that the close vote should be removed. But I think there should be a middle step between a comment and a close vote.

Comment: I very often see this pattern "Question is missing X and Y" -> OP gives *some* information that covers one of these (at best) -> "Sorry, but you still miss Y" -> OP points out they supplied some information before -> "But you are missing Y" -> OP may add more information for X or otherwise not supply Y. Etc. I don't think it's the *majority* of questions from new users but it does happen often enough that I don't think this FR is good as it stands - wiping the comments that ask for stuff will mean that the whole "We need Y" is going to be even more annoying to ask for.

Comment: @nickzoum: What for? Either it can be answered, then the comment is useless. Or it can't, but than it should be closed to prevent guessing answers.I'm not sure what  kind of questions would qualify for a request-for-info-comment but not for a close-vote. Or better to ask: If I leave such a comment and op doesn't respond, when should then the close-vote be cast? Do I have to keep track of all such comments and come back a day later to see if op has provided the information and if not vote to close?

Comment: @TemaniAfif They obviously should. But they may not include code that they might not be rellevant (but in reality is not). And to err is human, you could just forget to add some information to the question.

Comment: @BDL If the user has supplied a fair amount of information but just not quite enough (i.e. `could you show us at that function declaration`, `what does your config file look like` etc), then some people might still be able to give answers due to their experience, while others might need a bit more info.

Comment: Just use close votes. If the question gets edited into shape, it can be reopened. If it doesn't, then using an edit request flag instead wouldn't have made it any better.

Comment: Could such comments not be deleted as obsolete anyway with reason "It's no longer needed. This comment is outdated, conversational or not relevant to this post."?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like the idea in theory, but I agree with the comments that it could be messy in practice.

At first it would likely be fine. People might even actually use it as intended. Then, users who feel their questions are fine, what are you talking about? They'll edit fluff into their post and delete the comment. The commenter will return, make another edit request, and the cycle will repeat.

Eventually, this will either draw a mod's attention and get shut down, or end in some kind of edit war or argument and a mod will still have to get involved.

Now, admittedly, I don't see it getting that bad on every single post. But I do see that happening more often than it being used properly.

Meanwhile, I feel that if you care about an OP editing their question into shape, you can favorite the question so you'll come back and check on it in a bit. There's no reason you can't keep an eye on it and clean up your own comments if/when they become irrelevant, and continue guiding the user to fixing their question as necessary. I've done so here on Meta a time or two, when I've felt it was both possible and worth the effort.

TL;DR: While it sounds like a nice idea, I think it'd be misused a little too much. I also feel that what we have currently, while a little more effort on the commenter's part, works just fine for helping to guide a new user to fixing their questions. (If one so desires.)